# Regex Golf: It Never Ends

Tags: regex

I've been teaching myself regex for fun and I'm having real trouble moving past this level in Regex Golf. I know this can be done with a $, but the game is asking you not to do that. Any pointers or suggestions?

I've tried ([/w]*(fu)), [/w]*[fu]*[^/w]* and a few others

https://alf.nu/RegexGolf

[image: Challenge Link]

Comment: It has been asked on SO. Use `(?!.)`

Comment: How about just using a word boundary `fu\b`

Comment: fu\b works great :)

Answer (score 14):

You can try to use `fu\b`. `\b` means match the word's border.There is a picture to show how to match the borders.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The shortest regex for this question is `u\b`. You don't need the `f` :)

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
fu(?!.)
```

`(?!.)` will fail the match if there is a char immediately to the right of the current location.